# Webpack not including all our js and jsx file, even those in the same directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

We are trying to upgrade our React.js application which uses WebPack to build. In our upgrades we are moving from Webpack 1.0 to 2.0 and I have made the "necessary" changes for the upgrade. It is building, and compiling, however, when I look at the files included, it is a very smaller scale of the files it was including before.

For instance, we have 34 files in our React Flux Actions directory. Some files have .js extension some .jsx. However, of the 34 files, only 1 is showing up in the build. What happened to the other 33. This one has .js extension but there are more .js files in that directory too.

What am I missing?

This is our main config file.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var StringReplacePlugin = require("string-replace-webpack-plugin");
var Environment = require('./js/environment');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './js'
  ],
    output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new StringReplacePlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: true,
          failOnHint: true
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'jsx')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader' ]
    },
    {
      test: /js\/constants.js$/,
      loader: StringReplacePlugin.replace({
        replacements: [{
          pattern: /localhost/g,
          replacement: Environment.getBackendURL
        }]
      })
    }]
  }
};
```

This is our hot reload local version, I think both files are used, the one above and this one. But I am only doing "npm run build" command right now, then running "npm run local"

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './js/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build-hot'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: true,
          failOnHint: true
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'jsx')
    ]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'babel-loader' ]
    }]
  }
};
```

Based on Michael's answer below, there is one I did find that is different and feels like could be the reason, but I did not see anything in Webpack2 for pre-loaders. Here is it.

```
preLoaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: "source-map-loader"
  }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack starts looking at your entry point(s) and only includes files that are being imported, it doesn't just include every file in your project (as described in [Concepts - Entry](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#entry) of the official docs).

As your entry point is `./js` it will start with `./js/index.js` (that's how Node.js and therefore webpack handles importing [Folders as Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules)), so you're not including every file in that directory. And if you don't import them in `./js/index.js` or in its dependencies, the files won't be included at all. Presumably you don't and that's why only this one file is being included in the bundle.

This behaviour hasn't changed from webpack 1 to webpack 2. It's rather surprising that it worked differently with webpack 1, but maybe you changed something in the migration process that you aren't aware of.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Yes there is definitely things changed because of the changes between web pack 1 and 2 with modules/loaders/resolve etc. I will check the history of the files in git to see if anything sticks out.

Found one, going to update my question with it at the bottom

Comment: None of the mentioned options include any file. Loaders are only applied to the imports, `resolve` especially `resolve.modules` only tells webpack where to look for the modules that are imported.  Only `entry` would have an effect on that, which should contain what is necessary for the app to function. For the `preLoaders` see [Migration Guide - preLoaders](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-preloaders-and-module-postloaders-was-removed).

Comment: Thanks again Michael. Those were the only differences I found in our config files from 1 to 2 was the pre-loader. Everything else has been correctly converted to 2 without removing any other options. So I am at a loss. I am so much better at understanding Maven. ;)

Comment: Could the way we import affect this. For instance, we have a lot of these...

var keyMirror = require('keymirror');

Comment: That's fine. If you don't get any error webpack found the module. With your `resolve.module` it would first look in `node_modules/keymirror` then `js/keymirror` and lastly `jsx/keymirror` and stops once it found a module. You need to look what you `require` in `js/index.js` (your entry point) and then into the modules you require and so on, only these are included.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Everything that is there is exactly as it was using web pack 1 and would include every file we have. we did not change the require or imports of that file. So there has to be some other way to tell WebPack to include every file under our /js directory.

Comment: Could it be a lot of our files have .js extension and now they need to be changed to .jsx?

Comment: js to jsx extension did nothing. I think changing the require to import did do a big trick. Looks like I am now getting all my files and now my issues are back to code related changes.